# Gtk.DrawingArea mouse events using Vala

Tags: mouseevent, gtk3, vala

I have been trying to receive mouse events on my `Gtk.DrawingArea`, using Vala, with no success. Specifically I am sub-classing `Gtk.DrawingArea` and in my constructor I add the events I want to receive:

```
this.add_events (Gdk.EventMask.ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK |
                 Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
```

Then, in the same constructor below, I register signal handlers for these events:

```
this.enter_notify_event.connect (
        (page, event) => {
            stdout.printf("mouse entered !!! \n");
            return true;
        }
);

this.button_press_event.connect (
        (page, event) => {
            stdout.printf("mouse click \n");
            return false;
        }
);
```

I tried both `return true` and `return false` to check what happens in both cases. However I see no messages on the console when I move the pointer on the `Gtk.DrawingArea` or when I click on it. I even set the events for the top `Gtk.Window`:

```
this.set_events (this.get_events() |
                 Gdk.EventMask.ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK |
                 Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
```

but the events don't seem to get received. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems correct although it's not a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would point out the callback handlers prototype as being incorrect but since you're not using event data it should not be a "problem". The callback prototypes for `enter_notify_event` and `button_press_event`only supply the event, so the page argument it's incorrect.

Anyway, i tested with a very simple and raw code and it worked. Please verify:

```
using Gtk;

public class MyWidget : Gtk.DrawingArea {

    public MyWidget () {
        this.set_events (Gdk.EventMask.ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK |
                         Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

        this.enter_notify_event.connect ((event) => {
            stdout.printf ("mouse entered !!! \n");
            return false;
        });

        this.button_press_event.connect ((event) => {
            stdout.printf("mouse click \n");
            return false;
        });
    }
}

public void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);
    var window = new Gtk.Window ();
    window.add (new MyWidget ());
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit); 
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
}
```

Compile with `valac test.vala --pgk gtk+-3.0`.

The result is:

[image: result]

Using **Vala 0.30.2** and **Gtk+ 3.18** on **Fedora 23**.